# HTML5 Video option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, video

Now it may seem like a dumb question but for in regard to html5 video, is it possible to show the video poster once you navigate away from the page? 
Example, I have a JQM page that has a html video in it with a poster assigned to it. When I navigate away from the page, I have a little script that sets the play time back to 0 and pauses the video

```
<script>    
 var video = document.getElementById("video");
 $("#trigger").bind("click", function(){
        video.pause();
        video.currentTime = 0;});
</script>
```

This works but I also want to be able to display the video poster as well. Is there a way to do this though my javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by navigate away from the page? If you mean go to another page in the same browser window, there is clearly no reason for displaying a poster? Do you mean pausing the video or the browser window loosing focus?

Comment: By navigate away, I going to a different JQM page by using the default `pageChange` event that makes up JQM navigation. Because I'm technically not doing full reload of the document, the video still plays in the background. So when someone goes to a different page in the document, I want to video to "reset it's self"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the poster via javascript anew to "restore" the poster:

```
<script>    
var video = document.getElementById("video");
$("#trigger").bind("click", function(){
    video.pause();
    video.currentTime = 0;
    video.poster = "yourPoster.png";});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but it only flashes the poster img for a moment and then goes to a black pause screen. I did some research and found that the poster will show before the request for the video is made, but afterwards it won't be visible since you cant, to my knowledge, clear the video out of the cache. Thanks for the help